# Not seeing option of uploading graph file in Tensorboard using FireFox

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to get the graph using TensorBoard for MNIST example.
I checked other tutorial, questions and it seems uploading file option is not coming under graph menu for me but I haven't found the reason for this.

[image: Screenshot of TensorBoard on my laptopre]

P.S. I am able to generate graph file using write_graph which I want to display on TensorBoard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using it on chrome instead of Firefox.

It isn't working on my Firefox too.

See this discussion for more info:
[Is anyone else having trouble viewing the tensorboard/graph tab in firefox?](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/Lc7Y_6UEFOM)